# Variac Vs Motor Control

Tags: motor, transformer, power-electronics, motor-controller

I am a beginner. I want to purchase a variable AC power source for my personal lab, and I am having a lot of difficulties getting a good variac in my region whose shipping cost is not 5 times the price of the device.

However, I noticed that variable motor speed controls basically work the same way, they vary output voltage, and my question is can I buy a motor speed control and have it do the same things as a variac?

What are the fundamental differences between the two?

Comment: Show us an example of the type of motor speed control you have in mind. There are many kinds, some might work if the hardware is good enough and the software allows, but a variac will produce a cleaner sinusoid than pretty much any motor speed control that isn't specifically designed to output a clean sine wave (and the vast majority of motor speed controls are do not since the motor is not very picky). The limitation of a variac is you can't change the frequency. I imagine that the type of variable frequency drive that will produce the clean output you have in mind is very expensive.

Comment: @DKNguyen https://www.banggood.com/4000W-Variable-Voltage-Controller-Motor-Speed-Controller-Switch-Electric-Regulator-Thermostat-Transformer-p-1515993.html?rmmds=search&ID=47184&cur_warehouse=CN

Comment: @DKNguyen That is the link to the motor controller I am trying to purchase

Comment: No. That will not do it. Nothing that looks like that will do what you want.

Comment: @DKNguyen Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Not really.. =( Generating a clean high power sinusoid varies in voltage and frequency is a tricky thing. How much power are you after?

Comment: I'd just bite the bullet and get the Variac.  A Variac isn't isolated, so you probably want an isolation transformer to go with it for safety reasons.  If you really need to vary the frequency, then that's a whole different story.  Coincidentally I just built a variable voltage/frequency AC source with GAN FETs, but it's not something I would recommend for a beginner.

Comment: They claim that thing's 4 kW‽ And that it's both a motor controller and a thermostat‽ Now I want to know what on earth is in it, probably good for a laugh.

Comment: And yes, if you want a variable frequency drive at a few kW and pure sinusoid, you're looking at at least $10k, probably $20k.

Comment: You could build an itty-bitty genset where you have a little AC generator driven by a motor. You adjust the field current in the AC generator and its speed to get the voltage and frequency you want. You never did mention your desired power level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I buy a motor speed control and have it do the same things as a variac?

No.

> What are the fundamental differences between the two?

A Variac reduces the voltage without modifying the sinusoidal waveform. A Variac is a variable-ratio autotransformer.

The AC motor controls that provide good motor performance are variable frequency drives (VFD). They simultaneously reduce the voltage and frequency with the voltage generally proportional to frequency. It would be quite difficult to make a VFD reduce the voltage without reducing the frequency. A VFD rectifies the incoming voltage to provide DC. It then uses switching techniques to synthesize an approximation of a sine wave. With an AC motor load, the current is quite sinusoidal. With other loads, results will vary. Since three-phase motors are best for this type of control, nearly all of the many models and brands on the market have three-phase output.

The "motor controller" for which a link is provided in a comment, is almost certainly a triac voltage control. It is more suitable for dimming lights and controlling heaters than it is for controlling motor speed. It would work for controlling a universal motor and to a very limited extent, some types of single-phase induction motors driving a fan or centrifugal pump. The output waveform is shown below for three voltage levels: (A) output voltage nearly equal to input voltage, (B) output slightly lower than input voltage and (C) output voltage much lower than input.

[image]

Source: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Phase_control.svg

Alternatives

You will not likely find anything comparable at a reasonable price. You should probably consider more carefully what you really need. You may be able to find an assortment of fixed-ratio transformers that will satisfy some of your needs. For low power, you may be able to use a variable transformer for a toy train. For a higher voltage at an even lower current, you can use a fixed-voltage transformer to step up the output.